# show that there exists a unique subfield $H$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_9)$ such that $[H:\mathbb{Q}]=2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\xi_9 = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{9}}$, I want to show that there exists a unique subfield $H$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_9)$ such that $[H:\mathbb{Q}]=2$.

Is this correct? In that case How one can prove this?

I know for odd prime $p$, $\exists L$ such that $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=2$ where $L$ is the unique intermediate field of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$. In fact I know $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\pm p})$. [Unforntunately I don't know the proof] but $9$ is not a prime, so I am not sure whether this is right or not.

Comment: What's the proof you know when $p$ is a prime? The proof I know would work for odd prime powers as well

Comment: @Mathmo123, Oh really, can you give me some references? Even for odd $p$, I don't know the proof but what I know is just a statement.

Comment: The question is what you know. The proof I know is: the Galois group of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{p^n})$ is $(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)^\times$, which is cyclic of order $(p-1)p^{n-1}$, so it has a unique index two subgroup. But that might not be useful to you!

Comment: Once you know there is a unique quadratic subfield, you know its the same as the unique quadratic subfield of $K=\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$. Since $K$ has discriminant $p^{p-2}$, the quadratic subfield must have discriminant $p$. So it must be $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p^*})$, where $p^* = \pm p$, chosen so that $p^*\equiv 1 \pmod 4$. There are certainly other proofs though!

Comment: You can observe that $\zeta=\xi^3=\exp(2\pi i/3)$ satisfies the equation $x^2+x+1=0$ and hence $H=\mathbb {Q} (\zeta) \subseteq \mathbb{Q} (\xi) $ is the desired subfield with index $[H:\mathbb{Q}] =2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_9$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $X^6+X^3+1$ (see e.g. Wikipedia article "Cyclotomic polynomial"), you know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_9):\mathbb{Q}]=6$. So the Galois group of this extension is of order 6. Therefore it can either be $\mathbb{Z}_6$ or $S_3$. Now there is a theorem by which the groups $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_9)/\mathbb{Q})$ and the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic. The multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ happens to be $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z},+)$ as $\phi(9)=6$ and $9$ is the power of an odd prime.
So the Galois group of the extension must be $\mathbb{Z}_6$. But this group has a unique subgroup of index two, so the extension can only have a unique subfield of degree two.

Comment: Thanks. Once $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_9)/\mathbb{Q})$ is cyclic, then the other things are trivial! Due to$\phi(p^n) = p^{n-1}(p-1)$ is even, and hence has a uniuqe subgroup of index two.